# Failed to precompile Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp on Armbian Stretch

Tags: linux, mono, installation, freeze, debian-stretch

I'am running Armbian Stretch on a NanoPi-NEO Core2 and i'am trying to install mono-complete.
The whole installation worked well but at the end a postscript will try precompile a few assemblies. Most of them are working fine but it always hangs on "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp".
My whole SSH-session is freezing after a few minutes.

Sometimes it gives up after 2 hours and only write "Dependency problems".
Does anyone have an idea how to get more information on that dependency problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is out of RAM. You can start 2 parallel ssh session - in one start 'htop' and in other start install or reinstall mono-complete and see that all operations hangs after swap is filled. Raspberry PI 3 have only 1GB of RAM and default swap is only 100MBytes. So you need to extend swap file

First edit `/etc/dphys-swapfile` extend parameter `CONF_SWAPFILE` to 500 (It means 500 MBytes - it is enough)

if you use vim command will be: `vi sudo vi /etc/dphys-swapfile`

Then reload swap file settings

```
sudo dphys-swapfile setup
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

P.S. For restart interrupted install you need use

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp' it also takes a while for compiling 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic' - don't worry, just look in htop in parallel ssh session how it goes :-)